# enable/disable frag & vert shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Currently I'm using

```
glUseProgramObjectARB(ProgramObject);
```

and

```
glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
```

But it doesn't switch back properly，and gives me an “invalid operation glError” along these lines

```
void updateAnim_withShader()
{
    int location;

    location = getUniLoc(ProgramObject, "currentTime"); 
    ParticleTime += 0.002f;

    if (ParticleTime > 15.0)
        ParticleTime = 0.0;

    glUniform1fARB(location, ParticleTime);
    printOpenGLError();
}
```

What's the proper/right way of doing it(enable/disable shaders)?

[my code files(Temporary link removed )][1]

Comment: Please show us more code. So far I can only make assumptions, and right now I'm guessing you're trying to get a uniform location without a shader bound, which quite expectedly gives you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location` is -1, because the actual `currentTime` uniform was not used in a shader.